# Adding labels to contours created with the rendering option of rasters in QGIS 3.16

Tags: raster, qgis-3, labeling, contour

Is it possible to add labels to raster contours created using this option in the "Render Type" under "Raster symbology"?

For reference, this is the dialogue:

[image: QGIS screenshot of layer properties - symbology - band rendering - render type - contours]

Comment: I don't think so, but you could try to convert raster to vector and then add labels.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.